# Disable Excel-Like filtering for Some columns - Telerik C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

By enabling Excel-Like filtering for `RadGridView` all of the columns will have a filter button. I need to disable `Excel-Like filtering` for some specific columns and hiding the excel filtering button for that column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution using `RadControlSpy`, for hiding a excel-like filtering button I should manage `ViewCellFormatting` event like this:

```
private void gridShop_ViewCellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellElement is GridHeaderCellElement && e.Column.Name == "IDCol")
        (e.CellElement as GridHeaderCellElement).FilterButton.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to access children of `RadGridView` and change `Visibility` property to Hidden :

```
int columnIndex = 1; 
((Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridFilterButtonElement)(this.radGridView1.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(2).GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(2).GetChildAt(1).GetChildAt(columnIndex ).GetChildAt(0))).Visibility = Telerik.WinControls.ElementVisibility.Hidden;
```

[image: screenshot]

Tested on : `Telerik 2015`, `visual studio 2013`

**Remember** : do **NOT** use this command before initializing Form/GridView like constructor.

for example i use it on form load:

```
private void RadForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex = 1;
    ((Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridFilterButtonElement)(this.radGridView1.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(2).GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(2).GetChildAt(1).GetChildAt(columnIndex).GetChildAt(0))).Visibility = Telerik.WinControls.ElementVisibility.Hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version, there is a column property, *AllowFiltering*, that you can set to true or false.

```
this.RadGridView1.Columns["MeetingNumber"].AllowFiltering = false;
```

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/filtering/excel-like-filtering

Scroll down to "Enabling Excel-like filtering" for a description